# Perl TK BrowseEntry ComboBox default option

Tags: perl, combobox, perltk

I've taken over a Perl TK project in house.  I'm wondering how you set the default value for a combobox which uses the `BrowseEntry` library.

Here is how the combobox is constructed.

```
$tm->ComboBox(
                  -variable    => \$invoice_per_country,
                  -font        => $main::UserPref->{'ListFont'},
                  -background  => 'white',
                  -relief      => 'groove',
                  -width       => 40,
                  -takefocus   => 1,
                  -listwidth   => 60,
                  -listheight  => scalar @invoice_countries,
                  -forcematch  => '',
                  -options     => [ @invoice_countries ],
                  -buttontakefocus => 0,
                  -disabledforeground => 'black',
                  -disabledbackground => 'white'

                 )
                 ->pack(-side => 'left',
                        -anchor => 'nw');
```

The `invoice_countries` contains two values:  `('Canada', 'United States')`.
I was wondering how I make the United States the default value without switching the order of the values (we will add more countries).

Comment: It should reflect whatever value is in $invoice_per_country, just set that to 'United States' prior to packing it.

Comment: Thanks Charles that did the trick.  Glossed right over it.  Not sure how I can accept your answer since you left it as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `variable` option on [`BrowseEntry`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/BrowseEntry.pod):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my @items = ('Canada', 'United States');
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry('300x300');
my $default = $items[1];

my $be = $mw->BrowseEntry(-label=> 'country', -variable=> \$default,)->place(-y=> 100);
my $lb = $be->Subwidget('slistbox');
$lb->insert('end', @items);

MainLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should reflect whatever value is in `$invoice_per_country`, just set that to 'United States' prior to packing it (or even after, PerlTk will follow the variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use configure method of browserentry
$sel->configure(-variable => );